# Fast 3d distance between N points python using networkx nodes in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, simulation, networkx

I've been trying to figure this out all day and I just can't get it right.

I'm currently running a colonisation simulation using site-to-site percolation. I am trying to scale it up to large numbers ~10^6 however the conventional numpy method for calculating distances I'm using scales quadratically so for such large runs the program runs for more than a day. I really want this to be faster. I've looked for solutions but I can't find anything that helps me with this as I have a custom class which is used in the simulation.

So I want distances of each node to all the others and if the nodes are within a D_max of each other an edge is drawn, allowing emigration between the two nodes.

```
`density = 0.14 #Stellar density per cubic parsec
 L = 100
Patches = int(0.056*density*L**3+15)
Distance = 5

nearand = np.genfromtxt('/Users/Skippy/nearand.csv', delimiter =    ',',usecols=np.arange(0, 3)).astype('float32') # a csv of 3d cartesian co-ordinates

G = nx.Graph()

xcoord = nearand[:,0]
ycoord = nearand[:,1]
zcoord = nearand[:,2]

class patch:
    def __init__(self,status=0,pos=(0,0,0)):
        self.status = status
        self.pos = pos
    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.status))

for i in xrange(Patches):

    Stat = 1 if np.random.uniform() < P_init else 0 # a parameter used in the algorithm later
    Pos  = (xcoord[i], ycoord[i], zcoord[i])

    G.add_node(patch(Stat,Pos))

for p1 in G.nodes():
    for p2 in G.nodes():
        Dist = np.sqrt((p1.pos[2] - p2.pos[2])**2 + (p1.pos[1]-p2.pos[1])**2+(p1.pos[0]-p2.pos[0])**2)

        if Dist <= Distance:
            G.add_edge(p1,p2)`
```

After this, the algorithm is run but the larger runs are held up on the distance calculations so it is only the distance needs optimising. Could anyone please help me with this? It looks similar to other problems, but I need to be able to draw these edges in the way the conventional numpy calculation calculates distances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few remarks from what I understood.
You want to create an "epsilon-neighborhood graph", computing distances from all nodes to each others then filtering if the distance is under a threshold epsilon.

Knowing that your graph is undirected, you only need to do (N x (N - 1)) / 2 computations. It is still quadratic O(n^2) but your loop to create the edges should be changed so that the inner loop always starts at outer loop index + 1. It will reduce the computations by half.

Now if you want to really scale, you should ponder if you could use approximate nearest neighbors methods since you use the standard L2 norm (Euclidean distance).

I suggest you take a look at [NMSLib](https://github.com/searchivarius/nmslib) or [Annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy) to do so. They have python bindings but are implemented in C++ under the hood for speed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, the nearest neighbour suggestion helped a lot and I have used a Ball Tree to get a csv with each nodes nearest neighbour nodes on it, I'm just trying to figure out how to draw edges like this.

Comment: Nice!  If it helped please consider upvoting and accepting the answer :). Good luck.